# combining dataframes in Pandas without considering zeros

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, dataframe, merge

I have two different data frames. 
First one has the following form:

```
"start time"  "end time" "Value1 " "Value2 "
     12:00     12:01       0         0
     12:01     12:02       1         2
     12:02     12:03       3         4
```

Second one has the following form.

```
    "start time"  "end time" "Value1 " "Value2 "
     12:00          12:01       0         0
     12:01          12:02       1         6
     12:02          12:03       0         0
```

For both data-frames, if Value1 is 0 then Value 2 is zero as well. (the same applies from Value 2 to Value 1)

The difference between start time and stop time is always 1 minute and both data frames have the same number of rows. (whole day or 1440 rows)

Now what I want to do is combining these data frames without considering 0s. So the right merged data has the following form

```
        "start time"  "end time" "Value1_1 " "Value2_1 " "Value1_2 " "Value2_2 "
          12:01          12:02       1         2            1         6
```

What I am doing is

```
    df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

This simply does not ignore the 0 rows. So I thought why not merge them first and then get rid of the 0 values. It's not a smart way but it will do it. 
I wonder if there is a better way in doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could merge the results of a query on the individual DataFrames if you want. I'm not sure it's any more elegant or efficient, though. Your approach seems pretty good too.

```
df = pd.merge(
    df1.where(df1['Value 1'] != 0),
    df2.where(df2['Value 1'] != 0),
    left_index = True,
    right_index = True,
    how = 'outer')
```

Since it's an outer join it will include records where there are zero values in one DataFrame and not the other. If you switch to inner, you can include only records where both df1 and df2 contain non-zero values for a given minute.